# Monitor Data transffer on Windows Azure?

Tags: wcf, azure

How can I monitor traffic going out of a wcf service (self-hosted) on Windows Azure ? The amount of data going into my stress-test app doesn't seem to add up to what I'm seeing on the pricing page (which doesn't seem to be updated live anyway). The service is using https and messages are pretty small. Is the SSL handshake traffic negligible? I also have a data-miner worker roler that continuously downloads data from the internet, but from what I've read, inbound traffic is free, so it shouldn't count in the OUT traffic.

How can I get a reliable traffic monitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Billing page is usually updated once a day (once in a 24hr period). So you have wait a lot until you see results of your stress test added to the billing page for your account.

One place that you can monitor this (among other KPI for you application) is the `MONITOR` tab in the `Management Portal`. You can navigate to your Cloud Service being under test, click the  MONITOR menu item, then click on the `Add Metric` at the bottom, and finally chose `Network Out`. This monitoring dashboard gets data every 5 minutes so it shall reflect network usage you are talking about.

Here is a screenshot of how to achieve this:

[image: Cloud Service Network Monitor]

Other option that you have is to use a [Network Performance Counter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc768048.aspx#XSLTsection133121120120) such as `Network Interface : Bytes Sent/sec`. You have to configure [Windows Azure Diagnostics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh411543.aspx) to [monitor that specific performance counter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh411520.aspx). You can then set a scheduled transfer period of 1 minute and dig into the table created by the diagnostics agent for data.

P.S. And yes, you are correct - `INBOUND` data for Azure is FREE.

Comment: This answer seems outdated. The old Azure Portal is replaced by the new one.

Comment: Oh, really? Can you accidentally read when the answer was posted?